# SQL - SELECT a list of items that belong to User "X"

Tags: sql

I have two tables - USERS and TASK tables. Let's say I have two users "X" and "Y", and in Tasks I have 2 tasks for "X" and one task for "Y". How can I do a select of tasks that only belong to X? The difficult part - I want to use this on an Android APP, so that the User logged in will get "his" list of tasks. (Don't worry about the connectivity, but only how the select part of selecting only "X" user tasks!)

In my mind I will put a "user_id" on TASK table, so every time that the user "adds" a new task, I will know from who is the task, but I have no idea how to check who is the user logged in.

Is this this the right way of doing it? I'm searching but with no effort/concrete answers so far.

thanks!

Comment: Is there more to your question? or does my answer cover it?  Please ask if you need additional help.

Comment: Both your and winkbrace responses had answered it! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have the user_id in the tasks you don't even need a join. You can simply

```
select * 
from   tasks 
where  user_id = 123
```

It sounds to me that you don't need help with the query, but with identifying the current user. And that is a totally different story.

Comment: Indeed. The problem is identifying the current user, then. I was just not sure if it was "good practices" to use "user_id" in it too. I'll be searching the "how to" of it. Maybe it is in the Webservice (.php) that makes the communication between the Json from Android and the Database. Something about credentials in it (I know nothing of PHP) Thanks for the enlightenment!

Comment: A simple solution, those are always the most elegant. +1 @Ntrlz, remember to mark as answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

`Tasks` needs some way to relate to users, so yes, a `user_id` column is a good idea.  As for how to join them in SQL it would simply be:

```
select
  t.*
from
  Users u
  inner join Tasks t on u.user_id = t.user_id
where
  u.user_name = 'X'
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks! winkbrace responded something that makes more sense for my doubt, because I need the "user_id" column on my Task table (every task has a "owner" that has to fulfill them, so just make sense to have it). So the problem is identifying the current user more then is the query. But hey, just learned how to get a column from another table in a select!

Comment: @Ntrlz, great, glad you solved it. If wink's post does it, make sure to mark it as an answer!  Good luck!